# slurm, make #SBATCH --array read the number of lines of a txt file

Tags: arrays, jobs, slurm, hpc

I have the following slurm script (`script.sh`) that will run on HPC 25 jobs in parallel with `#SBATCH --array=0-24`. Each job will take one variable from `file.txt` and use it as `$VAR` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name test
#SBATCH --ntasks 4
#SBATCH --time 00-05:00
#SBATCH --output out
#SBATCH --error err
#SBATCH --array=0-24

readarray -t VARS < file.txt
VAR=${VARS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
export VAR

cat test_"$VAR".txt
```

In this case I know the number of jobs to be run by doing `wc -l file.txt`, which returns `25`. Therefore each line of `file.txt` is a job to be run.

Is there a way I can avoid to do `wc -l file.txt` and make `script.sh` understand automatically the number of jobs to run?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a here document in bash to achieve this. For example, the following script shows one possible approach

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read number of lines in file supplied as argument
nline=$(wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}')

# Create the Slurm script ($ used in script need to be escaped: \$)
sbatch <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name test
#SBATCH --ntasks 4
#SBATCH --time 00-05:00
#SBATCH --output out
#SBATCH --error err
#SBATCH --array=0-$(( nline - 1 ))

readarray -t VARS < $1
VAR=\${VARS[\$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
export VAR

bash my_script.sh
EOF
```

Note: that variables that are part of the script, not part of the setup (in this case: `VARS` and SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`) must have their` $`escaped (i.e.`$`) otherwise the wrapping bash script will try to interpret them.

If this script was saved in a file `runarray.bash` and your file with one line per subjob was in `file.txt` you would submit the job with:

```
bash runarray.bash file.txt
```

Comment: hello. thanks but it does not work. the runarray.bash cannot read the VAR variables.

Comment: If they are available depends on how you are defining the environment variables. How is the VARS array defined in the original shell before you run the bash script to submit the job?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what you mean by:
"the runarray.bash cannot read the VAR variables"

`VARS` is defined in the job script by reading from the `file.txt` file and so everything is self-contained. What error message do you see that leads you to think the VARS variables are not able to be read?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on @AndyT's answer that I've learned from a coworker and now use it (or some variation of it) regularly.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name test
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 4
#SBATCH --time 00-05:00
#SBATCH --output out.%j.txt
#SBATCH --error err.%j.txt

# Get first arg from command line or error with message
ids_file=${1?ids file required as first argument}

# How many lines does that file have?
nline=$(wc -l $ids_file | awk '{print $1}')

# Check to see if this is running as a task. If not, replace this process with a SLURM array, with one task per ID.
if [[ "$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID" == "" ]]; then
     # Relaunch this script as an array
     exec sbatch --array=1-$nline $0
fi

# Extract line from file corresponding to the current task
# (i.e. first task gets first line, second task gets 
# second line, etc.)
VAR=$( sed -n ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p $ids_file )

# Could also use readarray -O 1 -t VARS $ids_file, etc

echo $VAR
```

Comment: This does not work for me, the submitted script exits because the `ids_file` argument is missing. I think that part needs to go in the if block also? Can't really get it to work.

Comment: @ShellfishGene Are you using SLURM? Is the IDs file the first argument after the script name on the command line? (Sorry, I just saw your question just now).